# Button inside angularjs directive does not work

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angular2-directives

I am using a directive twice in one page. Inside the directive I have placed a button which on click removes the first directive and shows the other. But the values don't change at all even when the ng-click function is firing. What am I doing wrong? Here's my HTML code.

```
<body ng-controller="mainCtrl">
<new-directive ng-show="firstDirective" passvar="first passing value"></new-directive>
<new-directive ng-show="secondDirective" passvar="second passing value"></new-directive>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.8/angular.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="app.js"></script>
```

The test.html file:

```
{{content}}, {{passvar}} <button ng-click="otherOne()">show other directive</button>
```

The JS file:

```
app.controller('mainCtrl', function($scope){
$scope.firstDirective = true;
});
app.directive('newDirective',function(){
// Runs during compile
return {
    restrict: 'E',
    templateUrl: 'test.html',
    scope: {
        passvar: '@'
    },
    controller: function ($scope) {
        $scope.content= 'Random Content';
        $scope.firstDirective = true;
        $scope.firstDirective = false;
        $scope.otherOne = function(){
            $scope.firstDirective = false;
            $scope.secondDirective = true;
        }
    }
};
});
```

Even for displaying the first directive, I am having to add the $scope.firstDirective = true; in the main controller, and not in the controller of the directive.

Comment: The scope in your directive is only referencing the scope of the directive, you probably need to use $rootscope or $scope.$parent to change variables of the main controller.

Comment: Why do you need a certain directive to hide/show another directive? What if you have more than two of them? Why can't you just let the controller decide what directive that should be displayed?

Comment: Because there won't be more than 2 of them. And they will be more complicated than what I have listed here. I have just added a simple one here to understand what am I doing wrong.

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because your directive's scope is isolated and `$scope.firstDirective` and `$scope.secondDirective` are on the directive's parent scope.

The simple answer is to use `$scope.$parent.firstDirective` and `$scope.$parent.secondDirective`.

Personally I would set something up like this:

```
app.controller('mainCtrl', function($scope){
    $scope.show = {
        'firstDirective': true,
        'secondDirective': false
    };
});
app.directive('newDirective',function(){
// Runs during compile
return {
    restrict: 'E',
    templateUrl: 'test.html',
    scope: {
        passvar: '@',
        show: '=showDirectives',
        shows: '@',
        hides: '@'
    },
    controller: function ($scope) {
        $scope.content= 'Random Content';
        $scope.otherOne = function(){
            $scope.show[$scope.hides] = false;
            $scope.show[$scope.shows] = true;
        }
    }
};
});
```

and template

```
<body ng-controller="mainCtrl">
<new-directive ng-show="show.firstDirective" show-directives="show" shows="secondDirective" hides="firstDirective" passvar="first passing value"></new-directive>
<new-directive ng-show="show.secondDirective" show-directives="show" shows="firstDirective" hides="secondDirective" passvar="second passing value"></new-directive>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.8/angular.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="app.js"></script>
```